# Hashset Concatenate using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, hashset

I want to concatenate two hashset but when I use Linq I get an IEnumerable and not a new hashset

```
   var hashSet1 = new HashSet<string>();
    hashSet1.Add("foo");
    hashSet1.Add("foo1");
    hashSet1.Add("foo2");
    hashSet1.Add("footoexclude");
    var hashSet2 = new HashSet<string>();
    hashSet2.Add("fooh2");
    hashSet2.Add("fooh3");
    hashSet2.Add("foo2h4");
    hashSet2.Add("footoexclude"); 
 var hres = hashSet1.Union(hashSet2);
```

Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `Linq` with `Hashset`(if possible). Hashset was designed for performance reasons and using LINQ will introduce a performance hit in addition to creation of a new set

Instead of `Linq union` use builtin `UnionWith`

your hashset 1 will contains a concatenation

```
   hashSet1.UnionWith(hashSet2);
```

The `UnionWith()` method is used to modify the `HashSet` to contain all elements present in itself along with elements in other (IEnumerable) collection with which the union is established.

Comment: `Do not use Linq with Hashset use UnionWith` - Reason?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal using linq with hashset is a bad idea for the simple reason that Hashset was designed for perfomance while `UnionWith` is just a builtin method that does not imply any delegate or anonymous method creation and no new setswill be created  AFAK